# Different ng-click based on another value

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I let the user to upload there own photo and while this happens I take the image, make it smaller, add attribute (ng-click), compile it and append to newelement. This is triggered once on photo upload:

```
 var myEl = angular.element(image); // getting an image
 myEl.attr('ng-click', 'openImage($event)'); // adding ng-click
 $compile(myEl)($scope); //compile
 newelement.append(myEl); // adding to an element in the DOM
```

The problem is that afterwards I want to either have ng-click attribute or dont based on the value which comes to `$rootScope.activeTab` (in one tab I want to have ng-click, in other - dont). Not sure yet how to handle such case.

`$rootScope.activeTab` is watched and changes dynamically based on in what tab the user is.

Tried something like this:  `myEl.attr('ng-click', $rootScope.activeTab === 'stickers' ? '' : 'openImage($event)');` but it does not work as it is evaluated once on the upload. When I switch to a different tab this value does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about removing the `ng-click`. You can just handle your logic in the `openImage` function.

```
$scope.openImage = function($event) {
  if ($rootScope.activeTab === 'stickers') {
    return;
  }

  // Do whatever you were planning on doing.
};
```

Comment: Wow, not sure why I was thinking like this, I mean in a such complicated way. Thanks! This has helped!

Comment: np - We all do it - we get so caught up in one way of solving problems, that we miss other ways.